# sum of probabilities doesn't match, using HistogramTools in R

Tags: r, histogram

I was using the package HistogramTools in R to create Histogram.

```
> H<-hist(1:100)
> sum(H$density)
[1] 0.1
```

Somehow the sum of the density is not 1, regardless of the data I use (I have tried several generated random data as well, and it is also not 1)

but then,

```
> sum(H$counts)
[1] 100
```

the total counts match the total number of data.

Am I wrong in understanding "density" or "relative frequency"??

Comment: You would find it informative to plot `H`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is essentially a duplicate. Its sort of covered in Silverfish's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133370/805) but I think there's an answer (maybe from whuber) elsewhere that's more direct. I just don't seem to be turning it up right now.

Answer (score 2):

`$density` property of an histogram object gives you the y-axis *values* of each bin. In order to get an area of $1$, you'll have to multiply it with the bin width. In your case, number of bins is `10` by default, which gives you a bin width of `10`. Multiplying it with `H$density` gives $1$. Try the following, which will give `0.2` when executed (here bin width will be `5`):

```
H<-hist(1:100, 20)
sum(H$density)
```