# Why does dbeta not sum to 1?

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, beta-distribution

Both `dpois` and `dnorm` in the code below sum to 1 (or thereabouts). This appears to confirm my understanding of the `dpois` and `dnorm` functions, which is that they represent proportions.

```
sum(dpois(x = 0:20, lambda = 5))
# 1

sum(dnorm(-10:30, mean = 10, sd = 2, log = FALSE))
# 1
```

But the output of `dbeta` does not sum to 1. Why is this?

```
sum(dbeta(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), shape1 = 2, shape2 = 4, ncp = 0, log = FALSE))
# 5.564
```

Answer (score 14):

The relevant property of a probability density is not that it *sums* (for evaluation on some particular $x$ values) to one, but that it *integrates* to one.

If you evaluate a density $f$ at $x$ values that form a regular grid with grid width $\Delta x$, then you have very approximately

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x, $$

which is why your initial two examples sum to almost one: here we have $\Delta x=1$, so we have approximately

$$ 1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i). $$

Compare a finer grid for the normal case:

```
> sum(dnorm(seq(-10,30,by=0.1), mean = 10, sd = 2, log = FALSE))
[1] 10
```

And of course, if we include $\Delta x$ in your calculation for `dbeta`, then we again approximate the integral correctly:

```
> xx <- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
> sum(dbeta(xx, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 4, ncp = 0, log = FALSE)*mean(diff(xx)))
[1] 0.9998333
```

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133370/22228 For a very similar - but not quite duplicate - question,  about why the area under a PDF equalled one, I produced a graph for pretty much exactly the equations you wrote (including the approximation with rectangles) and it even uses a beta distribution! Feel free to steal one of the pics - in fact the ggplot code for the plots probably still works so might not even be too much work to customise it for the given beta distribution

Answer (score 9):

`d*` functions represent proportions only with a discrete response. In fact, your `dnorm` example just happens to sum to one, but

```
> sum(dnorm(seq(-10, 30, by = 0.01), mean = 10, sd = 2, log = FALSE))
[1] 100
```

is 100! The normal and beta distributions are continuous, not discrete. Therefore, instead of summing to 1, they must integrate to 1, which is different.

Answer (score 9):

`dpois` is the [probability mass function (pmf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) a discrete Poisson distribution that can take integer values in $(0, \infty)$. If you sum over the probabilities for all integers, you should indeed get 1.

`dnorm` is the [probability density function (pdf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) for the normal distribution over the real numbers in $(\infty, \infty)$ and `dbeta` the pdf for a Beta distribution over $(0, 1)$. These will sum to 1, if you integrate them over their domain.

pdfs are the continuous distribution equivalent to pmfs, but that `sum(dnorm(-10:30, mean = 10, sd = 2, log = FALSE))` sums to 1 is pure coincidence (or someone giving you a trick question).

Comment: For your third paragraph: that this sums to one is not a coincidence, but the rectangle rule for integral approximation, with a rectangle width that just happens to be one because of the particular grid.

Comment: Yes, in a sense, but it wouldn't be true if the `sd` had been 100, or if `mean` had been 13,712. Someone carefully chose the grid points and was careful to space them 1.0 apart to avoid the need for a scaling constant.

Comment: The sum of the normal density at integer points being extremely close to $1$ (though not exact) is not a coincidence.  It is a result of the sum over all integers being $\vartheta_3\left(\pi \mu, e^{-2\pi \sigma^2}\right)$, at least in the Mathematica/Mathworld notation for [Jacobi theta functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), and this being close to $1$ for $\sigma^2>1$.  The exact limit being $1$ as the variance increases is not a surprise either: it is an increasingly good rectangular approximation to the integral.

Comment: `sum(dnorm(0:20000, mean = 13712, sd = 100, log = FALSE))` gives `1` at least up to rounding (the range for the integers needs to cover the values where the density is of a noticeable size).  Try `sum(dnorm(-200:200,mean=0,sd=0.1,log=FALSE))` giving `3.989423` and `sum(dnorm(-200:200,mean=0.5,sd=0.1,log=FALSE))` giving `0.0000297` for better counterexamples